# Loading Content best practices

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sort of new to JavaScript and something has been bugging me.
Say I have some code like this:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id") // id being a file name sans extension
    $('.content').load(id + '.php');
});
```

Everything works just fine, but something in the back of my head tells me that this is bad practice. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine but you can save some operations using **[this.id](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/XEZvL/)**

```
$('button').on('click', function() {   
    $('.content').load( this.id +'.php');
});
```

I like this article here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using the ID attribute for this purpose. Instead, you should use a custom attribute. For instance:

```
<button data-url="mypage">Click me</button>
```

Then get that attribute instead of the ID.

Comment: Thanks I will use custom atts for this type of thing from now on.